# How To Hide/Display Page Layout Information based on the selected picklist field

Tags: page-layout, lightning-page

I have a Picklist field (current Status) where I need to display the Page Layout information to the user based on the selected value in the picklist field.

I have seen a couple of similar posts where it was using Visualforce page, but is there any way we could achieve it without using LWC/VF page.

I want to display information of the HPI detail section only when the status is  set to old in the current status picklist field.

[image]

Thanks,
Vijay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the relative new Dynamic Forms.
With this new feature you are very flexible to style your record pages.

https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2019/break-up-your-record-details-with-dynamic-forms

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic Forms of Salesforce is the way to go. You can write filter criteria for the section based on the picklist value selected.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_migrate.htm&type=5

But Dynamic forms come with some limitations. Right now, Dynamic forms are supported for Custom Objects ONLY, not available for Standard Objects.