# Validation rule is not working as expected

Tags: validation-rule

I have created a validation rule whenever the picklist Field (status) is N/A I have to make another fields as not editable based on the picklist values .

Below is my validation rule  :

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL( status__c,'N/A'),
ISCHANGED( NHPMS__Re_Admit__c ),
ISCHANGED( NHPMS__Discharge_Date__c ),
ISCHANGED( Next_Appointment__c )

)
```

I am able to change my Next appointment (pickList Field) and discharge date (Date Field)

**Before Validation Rule**
[image: Before Validation Rule]

**After Validation Rule**
[image: After Validation Rule]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current validation rule says the following

Block the user if the **all of the following is true**:

1. `Status__c` = 'N/A'
2. `NHPMS__Re_Admit__c` IS CHANGED
3. `NHPMS__Discharge_Date__c` IS CHANGED
4. `Next_Appointment__c` IS CHANGED

In your screenshot, only #1, #3, and #4 are true. You are not changing `NHPMS__Re_Admit__c` so the validation rule does not block you.

Based on your requirement, it sounds like you either:

- Do not care if `NHPMS__Re_Admit__c` changes, in which case just remove it

or

- Actually just want to fire if *any of those fields change* (not all of them together).

For that second scenario, you should leverage OR to denote that any of those fields changing meets criteria

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL( status__c,'N/A'),
    OR(
        ISCHANGED( NHPMS__Re_Admit__c ),
        ISCHANGED( NHPMS__Discharge_Date__c ),
        ISCHANGED( Next_Appointment__c )
    )
)
```

The above will now block the user if the following is true:

1. `Status__c` = 'N/A'
2. Any single one of the 3 fields is changing

Comment: Thanks it's working as expected now i was using the and function as well but it was not working    i used the below it didn't work your solution worked fine Thanks for the help                                                                                                      
   AND(
    ISPICKVAL( status__c,'N/A'),
    AND(
        ISCHANGED( NHPMS__Re_Admit__c ),
        ISCHANGED( NHPMS__Discharge_Date__c ),
        ISCHANGED( Next_Appointment__c )
    )
)

Answer (score 2):

The formula of a Validation Rule doesn't tell us when data is valid, it tells us when data is *invalid*.

So right now, you're saying that if Status = 'N/A' *AND* all of those fields are changing, that's invalid.

What you've described is that you want the Validation Rule to complain if *any* of those fields are changed. Thus, you want to use `OR()` for the `ISCHANGED()` part.

You still need that outermost `AND()` though. Put in the language of logic, invalid data is when `Status = 'N/A' and (field1 is changed OR field2 is changed OR field3 is changed)`.

You should keep in mind that Validation Rules are generally not a great tool to allow some fields to be changed and require that others remain the same. It should work fine in this situation, but using recordtypes and page layouts is a superior approach.

Comment: +1 on the note about superior approach and considering the UX experience. Your suggestion or dynamic forms as suggested in their [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/352967/how-to-hide-display-page-layout-information-based-on-the-picklist-filed-selected) (if possible) would be better options.

Comment: so from the Dynamic forms  we can make the field as Read only instead of adding as validation rules which would better suit my requirement i have to make the Fields as read only when the Picklist Field Value is changed.